# How can i create multiple fargate profiles with single namespace and different labels using terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am trying to create fargate profiles for EKS using terraform, the requirement is to create multiple fargate profiles bound to single namespace but different label.

I have defined the selector variable as below :

```
variable "selectors" {
  description = "description"
  type = list(object({
    namespace    = string
    labels       = any
  }))
  default     = []
}
```

and the fargate module block as below :

```
resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "eks_fargate_profile" {      
  for_each               = {for namespace in var.selectors: namespace.namespace => namespace}
  cluster_name           = var.cluster_name
  fargate_profile_name   = format("%s-%s","fargate",each.value.namespace)
  pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_fargate_role.arn
  subnet_ids             = var.vpc_subnets

  selector {
    namespace = each.value.namespace
    labels    = each.value.labels
  }
```

and calling the module as below :

```
  selectors = [
      {
        namespace = "ns"
        labels = {           
          Application = "fargate-1"
          }
      },
      {
        namespace = "ns"
        labels = {
          Application = "fargate-2"
          }
      }
    ]
```

When i try to run terraform plan, i am getting below error :

```
Two different items produced the key "jenkinsbuild" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.
```

I tried giving (...) at the end of the for loop, this time i am getting another error as below :

```
each.value is tuple with 1 element
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

I also defined selectors variable type as ***any***, as well tried type casting the output to string(namespace) and object(labels), but no luck.

So could you please help me in achieving the same, It seems i am close but i am missing something here.

Thanks and Regards,
Sandeep.

Comment: I tried the same manually using aws console and it was successful

Comment: Can you share the value you provided for 'selectors' when this error occurred?

Comment: I have not given anything in default but given the values in module call as i mentioned above :

`selectors = [
      {
        namespace = "ns"
        labels = {           
          Application = "fargate-1"
          }
      },
      {
        namespace = "ns"
        labels = {
          Application = "fargate-2"
          }
      }
    ]`

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform, when using `for_each`, the keys must be unique. If you do not have unique keys, then use `count`:

```
resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "eks_fargate_profile" {      
  count = length(var.selectors)

  selector {
    namespace = var.selectors[count.index].namespace
    labels    = var.selectors[count.index].labels
  }

  ...
}
```